# Recv and printf

Tags: c

Just to be sure... Does this code below should print exactly the stuff, which was sent by server?
I'm getting some unwanted patterns like `^M5b3^M` , `^M800^M` etc.
I.e. instead of this:

```
 <P k="33,556,1" v="-0.166723"/>
```

I'm getting this:

```
<P k="33,556,1" v="-0.16672^M
2000^M
3"/>
```

Is this code buggy? Or is the data rather corrupted ?

```
 char * input_buffer = malloc(MAXLENGTH);

 for (;;) {

    bytes_received = recv ( socket_handle , input_buffer , MAXLENGTH, 0 ) ;
    *( input_buffer+bytes_received + 1 ) = '\0';
    if ( bytes_received == -1 ) {
      printf ( "An error occured during the receive procedure \n" ) ;
      return 0 ;
    }
    if ( bytes_received == 0 )continue ;
    printf ("%s", input_buffer);
  }
```

Comment: `^M` is probly a linebreak char?

Comment: If you receive 1 char, it goes into buffer index [0], so the null needs to go in index[1].  You are adding an extra 1.  Anyway, to allow the extra null to go in the buffer, you probably need 'MAXLENGTH-1' in recv().

Comment: How is `input_buffer` defined?

Comment: You should probably allocate MAXLENGTH + 1 to prevent the nul-termination from corrupting the heap. Probably not the culprit unless MAXLENGTH is really small.

Comment: Also, this is a matter of taste, but how about "input_buffer[bytes_received] = '\0'" rather than explicitly dereferencing a pointer displaced by an int?

Answer (score 1):

In case `MAXLENGTH` bytes had been read, this line

```
*( input_buffer+bytes_received + 1 ) = '\0';
```

writes beyond the allocated memory, which provokes undefined behaviour.

Also it writes the `0` terminator 2 bytes of the last character received.

1 To fix the former modify this line

```
char * input_buffer = malloc(MAXLENGTH);
```

to be

```
char * input_buffer = malloc(MAXLENGTH+1);
```

or modify this line

```
bytes_received = recv ( socket_handle , input_buffer , MAXLENGTH, 0 ) ;
```

to be

```
bytes_received = recv ( socket_handle , input_buffer , MAXLENGTH-1, 0 ) ;
```

2 To fix the latter, modify

```
 *( input_buffer+bytes_received + 1 ) = '\0';
```

to be

```
*(input_buffer+bytes_received) = '\0';
```

---

Also this line

```
if ( bytes_received == 0 )continue ;
```

does not make sense. If `recv()` returned `0`, the connection had been closed. No more data is to be expected via this socket descriptor.

---

All in all the code better looked like:

```
char * input_buffer = malloc(MAXLENGTH+1);
/* Add error checking here. */
for (;;) {

  ssize_t bytes_received = recv ( socket_handle , input_buffer , MAXLENGTH, 0 ) ;
  if ( bytes_received == -1 ) {
    printf ( "An error occured during the receive procedure \n" ) ;
    return 0 ;
  }

  *(input_buffer+bytes_received) = '\0';

  if ( bytes_received == 0 )
    return 0;

  printf ("%s", input_buffer);
}
```

Comment: No, buffer is much bigger, than received data.

Comment: Yes, it should be *( input_buffer+bytes_received  ) = '\0';

Answer (score 0):

`^M` is ASCII 13, i.e. carriage return. It's often used to separate "messages" in line-based textual protocols.

Check how the other party is doing its sending, if you don't expect to get it over the wire. If the connection is stream-oriented, you must have some separator and CR (or CR+LF) is often a good choice.

Comment: The whole "string" ^M5b3^M is unwanted.